# Regex Negative Lookbehind with spases on c#

Tags: regex, negative-lookbehind

i can't understand regex Negative Lookbehind..

I need not to catch '(this)' if there was a 'not' word some spaces before.
For example:

1. ... (this) - catch
2. ... not(this) - not catch
3. ... `not          (this)` - not catch too, but it do

Please tell me where i am wrong, i can't  make it work.
My template :

```
(?<!\bnot\b)\s*(\(.*?this.*?\))
```

And `(?<!...)` can't understand something like `(?<!\bnot\b\s*)`

https://regex101.com/r/mK1yQ1/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are using a wrong online regex tester, you need one supporting .NET regex syntax. **Regex101.com does not support .NET regex syntax.**

You may actually use

```
(?<!\bnot\b\s*)\(this\)
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!%5Cbnot%5Cb%5Cs*)%5C(this%5C)&i=notbbaa%20(this)%20%0D%0Aaa%20not(this)%20c%20aadcdcd%20%20(this)%0D%0Anot%20%20(this)%0D%0Artjtj%20bbg%20(this%2Cand%20that)%20%0D%0Aaa%20%20%20%20%20%20%20not%20bbd%20%20%20aa%20(this)%20)

**Pattern explanation**:

- `(?<!\bnot\b\s*)` - check and fail the match if there is a

  - `\b` - leading word boundary
  - `not` - `not` literal substring
  - `\b` - trailing word boundary
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\(` - a literal `(` symbol
- `this` - a literal string `this`
- `\)` - a literal `)` symbol.

Note that this pattern does not match `this` in `rtjtj bbg (this,and that)`. To make it match that `this`, you may add a `?` (one or zero) quantifier after the last `\)` -> [`(?<!\bnot\b\s*)\(this\)?`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%5cbnot%5cb%5cs*)%5c(this%5c)%3f&i=notbbaa+(this)+%0d%0aaa+not(this)+c+aadcdcd++(this)%0d%0anot++(this)%0d%0artjtj+bbg+(this%2cand+that)+%0d%0aaa+++++++not+bbd+++aa+(this)+). You may further adjust the pattern.

Comment: Unbelievable, i was so close.. Thank you so much.